# How to use `io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver` with vert.x

Tags: java, netty, vert.x

I am trying to use [vertx-ampq-client](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-amqp-client) on a Windows machine in a corporate environment where a VPN solution was replaced by zscaler. Now DNS resolution does not work anymore and I get:

```py
java.net.UnknownHostException: Failed to resolve 'some.host' [A(1), AAAA(28)]. Exceeded max queries per resolve 4 
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1120)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1067)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1038)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.access$700(DnsResolveContext.java:68)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$2.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:508)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:118)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.finishFailure(DnsQueryContext.java:380)
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext$5.run(DnsQueryContext.java:315)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:153)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
```

Interestingly DNS resolution via JDKs `InetAddress.getByName(brokerHostname)` still works but the custom DNS resolver implementation of netty doesn't seem to be able to handle zscaler.

**My Question is**: How can I configure vert.x/netty to use `io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver` instead of `io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver`. The former is based on `InetAddress.getByName` and would solve the issue.